# scalamock mocking java interface method varargs

Tags: unit-testing, scalatest, scalamock

I need to mock a method with varargs from a java interface

```
public interface MyClient {
    MyResponse indexPrivileges(IndexPrivilege... parameters);
}
```

and I am mocking it with

```
(mockMyClient.indexPrivileges _).expects(*).returns(response)
```

but get an error

```
[error] /projects/lib-scala-projects/src/test/scala/com/example/MyManagerTest.scala:67: value expects is not a member of com.example.parameters.IndexPrivilege* => com.example.MyResponse
[error]       (mockMyClient.indexPrivileges _).expects(*).returns(response)
[error]                                        ^
```

Also, I tried with passing a Seq of IndexPrivilege to no avail

```
(mockMyClient.indexPrivileges _).expects(privileges).returns(response)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working with [Scalamock 4.1.0](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.scalamock/scalamock_2.11/4.1.0), there's a few possibilities that I'm aware of to make this work.

The first one is using the `MatchAny` matcher in the `expects` method.  This would look like `(mockMyClient.indexPrivileges _).expects(new MatchAny()).returns(response)`.
This will allow anything that is passed to the mock (from [documentation](https://static.javadoc.io/org.scalamock/scalamock_2.11/4.1.0/index.html#org.scalamock.matchers.MatchAny) `Matcher that matches everything`). The downside to this approach, is that it matches everything.

The second approach is to use `ArgThat` matcher.  [ArgThat](https://static.javadoc.io/org.scalamock/scalamock_2.11/4.1.0/index.html#org.scalamock.matchers.ArgThat), is a `Matcher that uses provided predicate to perform matching`. Which means that you can perform whatever validation you'd like on the input to your function.  Say you just want to check that all values of `IndexPrivilege` is passed to the function, you could write the test like:

```
val indexPrivilegeLengthValidation = new ArgThat[mutable.WrappedArray[IndexPrivilege]](
                (irArray: mutable.WrappedArray[IndexPrivilege]) => irArray.length == IndexPrivilege.values.length,
                None
            )
(mockMyClient.indexPrivileges_).expects(indexPrivilegeLengthValidation).returns(response)
```

I'm confident that there are other ways to approach mocking varargs, but these two approaches have worked well for me in the past.